# Max height left/right column

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, and I hope someone can help me ...
I already wanted to leave warned that I am a beginner and people who have patience with me :)

Currently my html / css file looks like this:
[image: Problem]

and I'm wondering what it looks like this:
[image: Solution]

as you can see, after the contents of the "content" exceeds the "left" and "right", the "content" occupies the entire space

I'm trying to make the "left" and "right" always Occupies 100% of height regardless of the size of the "content"

my css code:

```
#left {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#0c0c0c;
    color:white;
    height:30cm;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding:5px;
}

#right {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#0c0c0c;
    color:white;
    height:1200px;
    width:200px;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding:5px;
}

#content {
    background-color:#0c0c0c;
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding:10px;        
}
```

I'm sorry guys, apparently my HTML code does not Appear to topic -.- 'I will let down the exact example of what I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

</head>
<body style="background-color:#0c0c0c">

<div id="header">
<a href="#link">
<img src="#imagelink" alt="some_text">
</a>
</div>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Início</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">S</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Relatar erros</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Guia do site</a></li>
  <ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;">
    <li><a href="#contact">Doar </a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Sobre</a></li>
    <li><a href="#login">Contato</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>

<!-- LEFT -->
<div id="esquerda">
<a href="#link">
<img src="#imagelink" alt="Banner">
</a>
<p>__________________________</p>
<br>
<a href="#link">
<img src="#imagelink" alt="banner">
</a>
</div>

<!-- right -->
<div id="direita">
<a href="#link">
<img src="#imagelink" alt="Banner">
</a>
<p>__________________________</p>
<br>
<a href="#link">
<img src="#imagelink" alt="banner">
</a>

</div>
<!-- CONTENT -->
<a href="#">
<div id="section">
<div class="imgOverlay" style="background-image: url(); height: 200px; width: 150px;">
<span class="tipo">DUB</span>
<span class="qualidade">HD</span>
</div></a>

</div>

<div class="paginas"> 
<span class="pages">1 de 1</span>
<a class="primeira" href="#link">«</a>
<a class="link pagina anterior" rel="prev" href="#link">&lt;</a>
<span class="extend">...</span>
<a class="page anterior" href="#link">1</a>
<a class="page anterior" href="#link">2</a>
<span class="atual">3</span>
<a class="page proxima" href="#link">4</a>
<a class="page proxima" href="#link">5</a>
<span class="extend">...</span>
<a class="link proxima pagina" rel="next" href="#link">&gt;</a>
<a class="ultima" href="#link">Última »</a></div>

<!-- FOOTER -->
<div id="footer">
Copyright© <a style="color:#990000;" href="#"></a><br>
2015-2016
<p style="color:#4d0000;"></p>
</div></body></html>
```

thank you for the answers, but solved my problem in another way, I opted not to use two columns and completely redid my html/css.

Comment: Please share your HTML code as well.

Comment: Which of the two do you want?

Comment: `Currently my html / css file looks like this` Where is it?

Comment: Question clear, and answer can be given if you could provide the html. My telepathy powers have waned over the weekend.

Comment: The best answer comes down to which browser support you need and if your header/footer has fixed height and what should happen when content doesn't fit available space, should footer then always be visible or pushed down by the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should give the content a specific height and `overflow: hidden` so the footer is where you want it to be.

Don't forget

`clear: both` in footer

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you with a simple example.

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
body {padding: 65px 55px;}
footer, header {position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; padding: 15px; background-color: #99f; text-align: center; font-size: 1.5em; z-index: 2;}
footer {top: auto; bottom: 0;}
aside {position: fixed; top: 60px; bottom: 60px; width: 50px; background-color: #999; z-index: 1;}
.left {left: 0;}
.right {right: 0;}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<aside class="left">Left</aside>
<main>
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat natus repellendus rem neque quos animi totam ea commodi dolorum! Reprehenderit earum voluptatum id a consequuntur dignissimos perferendis eaque fugit, temporibus!</p>
  <p>Mollitia quas fugiat id dolor autem delectus, iusto facilis velit sunt dignissimos illo ipsum, similique! Quaerat facilis sequi enim maxime, voluptatibus ut, dolorem quod fugiat. Quas nam illo suscipit officiis?</p>
  <p>Facere quaerat perspiciatis ex optio nisi eligendi corporis quo aut et libero totam iure nam quibusdam eius vel, pariatur, consequatur exercitationem laborum temporibus necessitatibus quia ab odio nesciunt eaque unde.</p>
  <p>Esse ullam, veritatis optio possimus ea delectus fuga at cumque natus voluptatum omnis, nesciunt a, sapiente expedita? Corrupti autem soluta nemo alias, id, eius dicta, a deserunt optio ea ipsam.</p>
</main>
<aside class="right">Right</aside>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try **Flexbox**

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/365/)**

```css
.main-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header, footer {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
}

.left, .right {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <header>
    Header
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>
</div>
```